# How to calculate the eigenvector of a many-to-many model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a many to many model representing a dependency graph. How can I calculate the eigenvector of that graph?

There's a Relation model:

```
class Relation < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :dependency, class_name: "Article"
    belongs_to :dependent, class_name: "Article"
end
```

And a Relation table:

```
create_table "relations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "dependency_id"
    t.integer "dependent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["dependency_id", "dependent_id", "user_id"], name: "index_relations_on_dependency_id_and_dependent_id_and_user_id", unique: true
    t.index ["dependency_id"], name: "index_relations_on_dependency_id"
    t.index ["dependent_id"], name: "index_relations_on_dependent_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_relations_on_user_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Ruby's Matrix::EigenvalueDecomposition class perhaps?

```
m = Matrix[ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
Matrix::EigenvalueDecomposition.new(m).eigenvalues
  => [16.116843969807057, -1.1168439698070447, -8.046297179356069e-16] 

Matrix::EigenvalueDecomposition.new(m).eigenvectors
  => [Vector[0.23197068724628633, 0.5253220933012341, 0.8186734993561815], Vector[0.8169642040610365, 0.09018835790853766, -0.6365874882439635], Vector[0.40824829046386324, -0.8164965809277259, 0.40824829046386263]]
```

See
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Matrix/EigenvalueDecomposition.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [rankable_graph](https://github.com/dcadenas/rankable_graph).

A "gem mostly writen in C with a pretty Ruby wrapper. It's intended to be used for big but not huge graphs, as those are better processed with a map-reduce distributed solution."